# Paypal Masspay problem

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I was testing masspay php sdk provided by paypal.com in my sandbox.But it gaves me an error when i tried to pay to one of my sandbox test account.here is the response from paypal server.can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
TIMESTAMP:  2011-08-16T17:25:06Z
CORRELATIONID:  112ecb6997405
ACK:    Failure
VERSION:    65.1
BUILD:  2055089
L_ERRORCODE0:   10301
L_SHORTMESSAGE0:    User not allowed
L_LONGMESSAGE0: The user is not allowed to send money through Mass Pay
L_SEVERITYCODE0:    Error
```

Comment: So the issue is `The user is not allowed to send money through mass pay`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get PayPal support to enable this account for MassPay.

- https://www.x.com/thread/54096

To fix this, contact the vendor via their support channels (forums, phone, email, etc).

Comment: i went there.One guy posted the same problem and i think one guy from paypal said i have enabled your account.So how can i ask them to enable my account to do masspayment?

Comment: ok sure i will do that.Thank you very much for finding me that post.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote and 'mark answer as accepted' to the answer that helped you the most! It's the reputation system at StackOverflow.

Comment: i have post my problem  there.but dnt knw when it will get solved

Comment: Post it either on the forum, or submit a ticket through https://www.paypal.com/mts/